# Why I can't index my react-app on google,yahoo and bing searches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, hosting, search-engine

Today I deploy my first website. I try to find my page on google search, but I cannot see my website on the google.

What is the next step to see my websites on the google, yahoo & bing searches.

My websites is: [www.smartdigital-cctv.com](https://smartdigital-cctv.com)

Comment: what are using, create react app or next js or gatsby.js ?

Comment: create react app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google generally have a hard time indexing Single Page Applications (SPA) beyond the first page. However, you can try to request Google to index undiscovered pages via the Google Search Console.

Check this [ReactJS SEO video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rKgF0rf009c&ab_channel=GoogleSearchCentral) from Google for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Google can index SPA (Single Page Applications) like reactJS, but it must be response fast enough or Google will see empty page. Other method: You can use Next.js to render on server. Check it https://nextjs.org/